# What DVD players allow easy selection of chapters/titles during playback?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, dvd, alternative, navigation

I need a DVD player that shows this:

[image]

That is Windows Media Player 12, it shows chapter and title that its playing.

Thanks in advance and please don't tell me VLC, because it doesn't have that feature.

Comment: Do you just need to select between titles/chapters easily? Or does it have to show them in a side pane whenever the video is playing?

Comment: yes need to select between titles/chapters easily when the video is playing.  where is the panel dont care

Answer (score 1):

## VLC

[VLC [image: Install vlc]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc) does let you select a different title and/or chapter while a video plays. I don't believe it can show a sidebar like Windows Media Player for this, but *the exact same functionality is accessible through the **Playback** menu.*

<sup>See below for alternatives, in case you don't want to use VLC.</sup>

The **Title**, **Chapter**, and **Navigation** submenus of the **Playback** menu in VLC let you select a different chapter, title, or both while playing a video.

(It only lists titles and chapters that are provided by the currently loaded video file or the current disc. But you can use **View** > **Playlist** to create lists of different media items and select between them.)

Here's a screenshot of a **Playback** > **Title** menu selection in VLC ([larger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9yVo.png)):

[image: VLC: Playback > Title]

That screenshot is from a Lubuntu system, running the LXDE desktop environment. But you do in the same way in any other desktop environment, including GNOME/Unity. The difference is that, in Unity, an application's menu bar will typically be at the top of the screen rather than in the application window under the title bar.

Alternatively, you can *right-click* anywhere in the video itself, and access the menus, including the **Playback** menu and its submenus. *This works even when VLC is in full screen mode.*

Here's a screenshot of a **Playback** > **Navigation** menu selection in fullscreened VLC ([larger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yGZV.jpg)):

[image: VLC: Playback > Navigation (in full screen)]

Different DVD's organize their menu hierarchy differently. The DVD shown above is divided into many titles, each with just one chapter. It's more common--especially for a DVD of a single artistic work like a feature film--to have a smaller number of titles (sometimes just one) divided into several separate chapters.

However your DVD is divided, the **Title**, **Chapter**, and **Navigation** menus in VLC let you switch from any title and chapter to any other. (They also usually let you select any of the top-level menus. For example, to jump back to the DVD Menu, use **Title** > **DVD Menu**.)

## SMPlayer

[SMPlayer [image: Install smplayer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smplayer) is one of a few players available for Ubuntu, besides VLC, that let's you switch to any title/chapter while playing a DVD.

SMPlayer is a bit rough around the edges. I'd suggest VLC over it, for playing DVDs. SMPlayer may ask you want version of `mplayer` you have installed. Assuming [mplayer [image: Install mplayer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mplayer) is installed, the answer is usually the latest version that SMPlayer knows about, at least these days.

SMPlayer might also ask you to configure the DVD drive, the first time it runs, as it does not yet always have the ability to figure out what drive(s) to play DVDs from. If your Ubuntu machine has only one optical drive, then your DVD drive is usually `/dev/sr0` (though `/dev/dvd` may also work).

And SMPlayer's support for *displaying* DVD menus is experimental. In my limited experience, it seems to usually work okay. Please note that this has little to no bearing on its ability to switch between titles and chapters via its own interface.

SMPlayer's **Browse** menu lets you navigate through the structure of the currently playing DVD, through its **Title**, **Chapter**, and **Angle** submenus. It also has menu items to switch quickly to interactive DVD menus (if you've enabled them in SMPlayer).

[image: SMPlayer: Browse > Title]

The **Title** and **Chapter** submenus of **Browse** in SMPlayer work mostly the same as the **Title** and **Chapter** submenus of **Playback** in VLC.

Like in VLC (as descrbed above), the menu bar in SMPlayer will typically appear at the top of the screen if you're in a Unity desktop; only a few applications override this and keep their menu bars inside the application window.

Also like in VLC, the SMPlayer **Browse** menu and its submenus are accessible while in full screen mode, by right-clicking:

[image: SMPlayer: Browse > Title (in full screen)]

## Kaffeine

Especially if you use a [KDE](http://kde.org/) desktop ([Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/)), you might wish to use [Kaffeine [image: Install kaffeine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kaffeine).

It will work without KDE as well, and installing it doesn't tend to pull in too many additional [dependencies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Glossary#D). (This is nice, as many KDE applications require large parts of KDE to be installed; Kaffeine does not.)

Kaffeine supports DVD playback, and has had full menu support [for some time](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kaffeine). It also supports navigation to any title, chapter, and angle of a DVD from the **Title**, **Chapter**, and **Angle** submenus of its **Playback** menu, or *directly* from the contextual menu that comes up when you right-click inside the video.

[image: Kaffeine: Playback > Chapter]

[image: Kaffeine: fullscreen contextual menu > Chapter]

<sub>To illustrate the techniques described, this answer contains a small number of *partial* still images from [*Reformation 1* (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reformation_1), [Sin by Silence (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_by_Silence), and [Pushing Hands (1992)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushing_Hands_%28film%29). I believe these circumstances constitute fair use.</sub>

Comment: thanks so much that really help. But in all that players you need to go to the menus and select from there, in WMP 12 i can see the movie and see the chapters in the panel. Any way for the moment i will use vlc or kaffeine, with already have installed, till find some other more convenient software

Comment: It's really weird how inconvenient it is implemented in most players. To see what chapter is currently playing in big m4b file or select a different chapter I must go through multiple levels of submenus? Or sometimes they show chapters on the progressbar as dots.. Are you kidding me, player's UX developers? :) Chapters must be shown as playlist! It's 2021 now. Still, I can't find a player that does this. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Parole media player  , show similar to me . check this image.

[image]

if you want to install . open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install parole
```

or you can install it from software center too.

Comment: yes i see, but that is a playlist, Right? is not the list from DVD Right?